# k-fold crossvalidation and independent models evaluation

Tags: cross-validation, model-evaluation

I have a question about using k-fold cross-validation.

From what I have read, there are several steps for using it.

1. Shuffle my data.
2. Train my model for
   each fold on training data and test it using testing data.
3. I get k different success-rates for the evaluation of the model so I take a mean and interpret it as the model's average performance.

Now for another model I repeat all steps, I get another average performance and I can compare these two models. Am I right?

Now comes the tricky part. Do I shuffle the data ahead of evaluation for each model?

I've tried searching this and haven't run into any solid mathematical argument. I think that both not-shuffling and shuffling before each model evaluation makes sense. Could you point me to some article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assumption 1:** All initial problems orders are uniformly random, and that the only question we have is: how to randomize the problems (i.e. should we randomize them for each model? or should we randomize them once for all models?)? (which I think is your question).

### Following assumption 1

If we model $k$-fold x-val as a function, I would suggest the following to represent the average accuracy of model $m$:

$$f(m,k,\mathcal{P}, o)$$ 
where $\mathcal{P}$ is the set of problems, and $o$ defines the order of the problems in $\mathcal{P}$ before they got partitioned into $k$ folds.

So, in other words, in my view, the score of $k$-fold x-val is *only* a function of:

- Model under evaluation (i.e. $m$).
- Total problems set (i.e. $\mathcal{P}$).
- Initial order of problems set before partitioning them (i.e. $o$).
- And total number of folds (i.e. $k$).

Let's now consider various cases and how they relate to the value $f(m,k,\mathcal{P}, o)$.

**Case 1:** If $k = |\mathcal{P}|$ (i.e. total number of folds is equal to total number of problems, then for any different orders $o_1$ and $o_2$, the scores are identical:
$$f(m,k,\mathcal{P}, o_1) = f(m,k,\mathcal{P}, o_2)$$

So in the case when $k = |\mathcal{P}|$, clearly the order doesn't matter.

But, in some cases it's impossible to have $k = |\mathcal{P}|$ without causing a class imbalanced in training or testing folds. So I think we should not be too happy about **Case 1**.

Let's look at another case where the order $o$ does not matter.

**Case 2:** For any orders $o_1$ and $o_2$, the following is true:

$$
\lim_{|\mathcal{P}| \rightarrow \infty}f(m,k,\mathcal{P}, o_1) = \lim_{|\mathcal{P}| \rightarrow \infty}f(m,k,\mathcal{P}, o_2)
$$

In my view this statement is true because of the *law of large numbers*.

But similarly to *Case 1*, I think we should not get too excited about this because usually our problems are not large enough to trigger this equality.

Let's look at another case that is more realistic.

**Case 3:** For a finite problems set, it is IMO very likely that there exists orders $o_1$ and $o_2$ such that:

$$f(m,k,\mathcal{P}, o_1) \ne f(m,k,\mathcal{P}, o_2)$$

This is an empirical thing. Personally, based on all datasets that I have evaluated against, the probability that this inequality is true is $1$.

Perhaps you can run a Monte-Carlo based simulation to estimate the probability that the inequality above is true as follows:
$$\begin{split}
=&\frac{\text{total num of times }f(m,k,\mathcal{P}, o_1) \ne f(m,k,\mathcal{P}, o_2)}{\text{total number of evaluations}}\\
=&\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n} I(f(m,k,\mathcal{P}, o_{1+i}) \ne f(m,k,\mathcal{P}, o_{2+i}))\\
>& 0 \ \ \ \ \ \text{(I think this is true for most cases)}
\end{split}$$
where $I$ is an indicator function that returns 0 if statement is false, else returns 1.

I think you wouldn't be surprised if it's $> 0$ for all your datasets.

So, clearly, for any models $m_1$ and $m_2$, and any orders $o_1$ and $o_2$, the following test -by itself- is not very meaningful:
$$f(m_1,k,\mathcal{P},o_1) > f(m_2,k,\mathcal{P},o_2)   \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$
because there are two variables: two models $m_1$ and $m_2$, and also two different orders $o_1$ and $o_2$. Therefore, you can't know which one is causing which. Is it due to the order $o_1$ that is very lucky and helping $m_1$ to score better? Or is due $m_1$ being really good? Or a mixture of other factors?

Alternatively, if you choose a single fixed order $o_1$, then (note that order is $o_1$ for both models):
$$f(m_1,k,\mathcal{P},o_1) > f(m_2,k,\mathcal{P},o_1)  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$
means that model $m_1$ is better than model $m_2$ when tested against $\mathcal{P}$ problems as ordered by the specific order $o_1$.

So clearly $(2)$ is telling us more information about the models than $(1)$.  I.e. at least now we could say something about models $m_1$ and $m_2$ even though it is still somewhat useless as it is speific to the order $o_1$, but at least better than $(1)$ that didn't even isolate the effect of the order!

So, $(2)$ tells us more information about the models, but it is specific to order $o_1$. Do we care? Usually, no. We don't care about the order. So while $(2)$ is better than $(1)$, it is still not very useful.

Therefore, we need to repeat $(2)$ multiple times (forget about $(1)$), each time with a different order $o_i$ (where $i \in \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$. Then, we need to perform statistical significance tests across all the orders $o_1, o_2, \ldots, o_n$, and then measure the $p$ value. Then we conclude that, for any $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, $f(m_1,k,\mathcal{P},o_i) > f(m_2,k,\mathcal{P},o_i)$ is the case only if $p \le \alpha$.

Therefore, we now define another $k$-fold x-val function that is *independent* of the order $o$ as follows:
$$
g(m,k,\mathcal{P}) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n f(m,k,\mathcal{P},o_i)
$$

But since we cannot realistically choose $n \rightarrow \infty$, we choose $n$ that is large enough. How large is large enough? I suggest the following:

- Large enough to give us a $p$ value that is less than $\alpha$.

**Important note:** choosing $n$ that is large enough (maybe $n=1000$) to give you a small enough $p$ value (maybe $p \le \alpha$) does not necessarily mean that model $m_1$ is significantly better than $m_2$. Instead, it ***only*** means this:

- **A1:** the order-independent $k$-old x-val process thinks that the score of $m_1$ is higher than that of $m_2$.

Which is a *different* answer than the following:

- **A2:** $m_1$ is better than $m_2$.

Simply calculating the $p$ value above to show *A1* does not show *A2*.

### Unanswered useful questions (beyond your main question)

- What if *Assumption 1* is violated? This could be interesting for time series problems?
- Is the number $n$ independent of the size of the problems set $\mathcal{P}$?
- How to show *A2*?

Comment: Thank you, that was the kind of answer I was looking for.

From my experience, people are only doing one cross validation whereas you advice to do this n=1000 times. Is one cross-validation a good estimate?

A2: I thought the whole point of cross-validation was to get an idea on which model is better. Could you elaborate little bit on this?

Comment: I didn't suggest $n=1000$, I just put it as an example to make my post more readable. I suggest you to choose any $n$ that gives you $p \le \alpha$ (usually you want $n$ to be smallest that satisfies $p \le \alpha$ so that you don't waste your time repeating for too long. As for *A2*, nope, $k$-fold x-val doesn't aim to show statistical significance due to the difference. It only tries to measure some statistic (like accuracy). However, answering whether the score of $m_1$ is better than that of $m_2$ is due to a systematic difference (as opposed to sheer dumb luck) is a different question.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to answer your other question: is doing $k$-fold x-val one time good? Well, I think we can't tell. It depends on how lucky the order $o_i$ was right? One way to find out is to repeat it with different initial orders $o_i$ for $i \in \{1,2,.\ldots,n\}$, then estimate the order-independent variant $g$ good enough that gives you a different that is significant for the $k$-fold x-val process.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing here is an example of Adaptive Data Analysis, ie. selecting a model by looking at the CV results of two or more models. This could be dangerous and a lot of research is being carried out right now on how to mitigate it.

So, take extra precaution when you're doing CV for many models. For a demo of the failure of cross validation, see[1].

[1] Rao, R. B., Fung, G., & Rosales, R. (2008, April). On the Dangers of Cross-Validation. An Experimental Evaluation. In SDM (pp. 588-596).

Comment: Thank you. Could you please give a few reasons on why CV fails, and a few examples on how to mitigate it?